# Sencha Touch: setTpl isn't not working in Ext.Container

Tags: templates, mobile, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm trying to display a simple template, but it seems like the template doesn't get added, as there is nothing added to the DOM. The code is called for sure and a container has the method [setTpl(tpl)](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.Container-method-setTpl). What am I doing wrong? The sample above is the most simple example I could imagine, but it doesn't work!

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.sample', {
   extend: 'Ext.Container'
   config: {},

   initialize: function() {
      this.callParent();
      var sampleText = '<div> why?? </div>';
      var t = new Ext.Template(
         sampleText,
          {
            compiled: true
          }
       );

       t.compile();
       this.setTpl(t);
   },   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML = template + data. So your next step is to call [`setData`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-setData). Check the docs for [`tpl`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-tpl). If what you want is to plug in some raw HTML that doesn't depend on data, you've got the [`html`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-html) config (and the corollary method `setHTML`). Last advice, if that's just for rendering some HTML, you don't need to use a container, a [`Component`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Component) would be enough.

Comment: That was it, thanks. When I call 'this.setData(null)' after setting the template, it works. No worries, won't use that template without data. Just wanted to put together a simple sample.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a class, but you also need to instantiate it. Try something like this:

```
Ext.create('MyApp.view.sample', {
  renderTo: 'some-div-id',

  // any other necessary config options
  // (see http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Container)
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'm instantiating it. The sample-app is being added, but only template is missing.